# Java scanner searches same pattern twice

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I expect that the following code will find all tokens of pattern available. I parse the shell command `iwlist wlp3s0 scanning`, so there is more than one access point always (repeating pattern).  I need to parse them all somehow.

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(commandOutput);
    String pattern = ".*?Address: (\\S*) .*?Channel:(\\d*) .*?Frequency:(\\S*) .*?Quality=(\\d*)/(\\d*) .*?Signal level=-(\\d*)";
    //s.findInLine(pattern);
    while(true){
        s.findInLine(pattern);    
        MatchResult result = s.match();
        for (int i = 1; i <= result.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println(result.group(i));
        }
    }
```

But it throws this exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException`.

How do I check if it has more matches while iterating through the loop instead of `while(true)` and the exception?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the `match()` method:

> **public MatchResult match()**
>
> Returns the match result of the last scanning operation performed by this scanner. This method **throws IllegalStateException if no match has been performed, *or if the last match was not successful*.**

But why is this a problem? There was a match performed, so can only be that it was not successful. Let's look at the doc for `findInLine` (the actual info is from the [variant accepting a Pattern argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findInLine%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29)):

> **public String findInLine(Pattern pattern)**
>
> Attempts to find the next occurrence of the specified pattern ignoring delimiters. **If the pattern is found before the next line separator, the scanner advances *past the input that matched* and returns the string that matched the pattern.** If no such pattern is detected in the input up to the next line separator, then null is returned and the scanner's position is unchanged. This method may block waiting for input that matches the pattern.
>
> Since this method continues to search through the input looking for the specified pattern, it may buffer all of the input searching for the desired token if no line separators are present.

So what soes this do? It matches the pattern, and puts the "marker" at the end of the string matched. But that does not contain everything from the actual line, so the next `findInLine` call will try to match what is left (line break chars, etc) - and will not be able to do so...

The Scanner has to consume everything until the end of the line to be able to go ahead by issuing a `nextLine()` call, and not using the returned String:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(commandOutput);
String pattern = ".*?Address: (\\S*) .*?Channel:(\\d*) .*?Frequency:(\\S*) .*?Quality=(\\d*)/(\\d*) .*?Signal level=-(\\d*)";

//instead of "true, use hasNextLine()"
while(s.hasNextLine()){
    s.findInLine(pattern);    
    MatchResult result = s.match();
    for (int i = 1; i <= result.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println(result.group(i));
    }
    s.nextLine(); // consume everything  from this line
}
```